# NodeJS - Pass vars between scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to make a GET request to a certain API and pass its response to a method in the outter scope. Is it possible?

```
var http = require('http'),
    magic = new Magic();

http.request('www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new', function(response) {
    var str = String();

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);

        // here
        // magic.load(str);
    });
}).end();

// or here
// magic.load(str);
```

The response `str` should be passed to `magic.load()`.

I get no errors but the object is not loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your console.log show anything?

Comment: You can do it this way https://pastebin.com/K5DCZFmn

Comment: What is `Magic`? Can you show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?